# Javascript: use object as function?

Tags: javascript, function, object, variables

How can i do this:

```
var obj = {x: 2, y: 4};
obj(); //return function
obj.x; //return 2
```

like jquery:

```
$.fn
$()
```

Comment: Could you provide some more detail?  I'm not clear what `obj()` is supposed to do, or what it is supposed to return exactly.

Comment: `obj(); //return function` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479510/what-javascript-concept-allows-for-the-same-name-to-be-both-a-function-and-an-ob/

Comment: `var func = function(arg1){console.log(arg1)};`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign properties to functions since functions are objects:

```
var obj = function ( ) {
    console.log( 'Called' );
};
obj.x = 2;
obj();
console.log( obj.x );
```

Comment: Thanks. but it calls both together. is it possible if i call obj.x it doesn't call obj() ?